# Can't click on an input element HTML using Selenium for Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm having an issue using Selenium on Python. Here is the whole error code :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div/div[3]/div[2]/form[1]/input"}
  (Session info: MicrosoftEdge=89.0.774.57)
```

and here is the element I'm trying to access :

[image]

The fact is that when I click on that element and copy the full XPath, here is what I have :

```
/html/body/div/div[3]/div[2]/form[1]/input
```

but it doesn't work for some reasons... I tried almost everything : with the name, with the value, with the normal XPath (which is `//*[@id="content"]/form[1]/input` by the way)

I'm using Edge Chromium and I use Python 3.9.0 and here is the code I'm using (everything work perfectly until the variable `telechargerReleve` :

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path="automation_drivers/msedgedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://login.unice.fr/login?service=https://ent.unice.fr/uPortal/Login")

usernameElement = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
passwordElement = driver.find_element_by_id("password")

usernameElement.send_keys("myUsername")
passwordElement.send_keys("myPassword")

login = driver.find_element_by_name("submit")
login.click()

mesInfos = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/a")
mesInfos.click()

intracursus = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr/td[2]/span[2]/a[3]")
intracursus.click()

telechargerReleve = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[3]/div[2]/form[1]/input")
telechargerReleve.click()
```

Thank you in advance,
Roux.

PS : Some texts may be in French so if you need a traduction or something, feel free to ask me!

Comment: use a more targetted XPATH.  Maybe by the text of the button.  (This is also how the user would find it...) Seems like it's the first form, there... but path based xpath's are brittle.  Depending on how the site works it may also need a webdriverwait...

Comment: ALl xpath based locators are NOT brittle. This is a fallacy. However some xpath can be brittle.

Comment: Assuming you are wanting that element that is highlighted in the HTML you should use find element by name.  It's available to use.  Make it easier on yourself

Comment: It seems you clicked an a tag prior to finding that element. Use a wait.

Comment: any change to the HTML (development or a Javascript update) can change the path to your webelement.  Since you are using a purely path-based XPATH there, it is brittle.  You could end up with another webelement because the path to the one you want has changed.  So it's not only brittle it's also not targetted to a particular element of the DOM, but rather a path that can change with updates.

Comment: I also tried with a Wait and a tag prior to find that element but unfortunately it doesn't work... I get a TimeoutException

Comment: I think it's related to iFrame or something like that

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I figured out what was the issue. The website used an `iframe` tag in the HTML for the button which was obviously the main reason why I couldn't click on it. What I edited in my code was the last 2 lines which I replaced with :

```py
seq = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')

for index in range(len(seq)):   
    driver.switch_to_default_content()
    iframe = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[index]
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,"telrelevepresences"))).click()
    except TimeoutException:
        pass
```

Thank you everyone for your answers !

Answer (score 0):

Induce a wait after your click the a tag.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,"telrelevepresences"))).click()
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```