# Selenium can't find element by id (tried XPATH as well) (Python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, iframe

Trying to fill out the form of a site and not matter what it can't find the element. I looked to see if maybe it was an iframe issue but I don't think so.

```py
    # For Browser 1
    browser1 = webdriver.Chrome(options=opts, service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
    browser1.get("https://www.msg.com/ufc-295/")

    browser1.implicitly_wait(2)
    
    first_name = browser1.find_element(By.ID, "field147946152-first")
    last_name = browser1.find_element(By.ID, "field147946152-last")
    email = browser1.find_element(By.ID, "field147946153")
    submit = browser1.find_element(By.ID, "fsSubmitButton5363561")
```

HTML code of the fields (looks terrible when I copy the html from inspect) so I will add an image.

[image]

Link if needed: https://www.msg.com/ufc-295/

Comment: Please copy the HTML into a code block (delimited on each end by `\`\`\``), it will look fine then.

Comment: implicit wait does not help with client side generated context like react 
use sleep(10) to see if it will resolve if it does take WebdriverWait into consideration 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566799/wait-until-page-is-loaded-with-selenium-webdriver-for-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code won't work because the website has an `iframe` tag in the HTML you are trying to access.

One alternative is to go to the form directly:

```
# the URL in the iFrame tag when you inspect the page
driver.get('https://msg-wmzqo.formstack.com/forms/ufc_295')
driver.find_element('//*[@id="field147946152-first"]).send_keys('First Name') #first name input
```

Another alternative is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66784543/6385519).

Comment: Thanks a lot, somehow missed the iframe url, def makes my life easier.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to iframe then u will be able to find the element

```py
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//iframe[contains(@class, '_1oz60')]")) #Switching to IFRAME <br>
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='field147946152-first']").send_keys("name_here")
```

Comment: I have another site with an iframe but no url that I can find right now anyways in the iframe, so I will probably use this approach, thanks!